# Creating Navigation from text file

Tags: javascript

i have following peice of code...

but showing error **Uncaught type reference Cannot call method 'split' of undefined  **

```
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var textFile = "nav.txt";
            jQuery.get(textFile, function (textFileData) {
                var EachLineInTextFile = textFileData.responseText.split("\n");
                for (var i = 0, len = EachLineInTextFile.length; i < len; i++) {
                    STORE_TO_REPLACE = EachLineInTextFile[i];
                    //STORE_TO_REPLACE: I would have to the entire format of your file to do this.
                    console.log(STORE_TO_REPLACE);
                }
            })
        });
</script>
```

nav.txt file is below

```
a a.aspx
b b.aspx
c c.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.responseText` part.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var textFile = "nav.txt";
        jQuery.get(textFile, function (textFileData) {
            var EachLineInTextFile = textFileData.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0, len = EachLineInTextFile.length; i < len; i++) {
                STORE_TO_REPLACE = EachLineInTextFile[i];
                //STORE_TO_REPLACE: I would have to the entire format of your file to do this.
                console.log(STORE_TO_REPLACE);
            }
        })
    });
```